# Dynamic virtualhost causing "client denied by server configuration" error

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mac

I'm trying to configure a dynamic virtualhost on mac:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.*.*
    ServerAlias *.*.*.*

    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Volumes/Work/webs/%2"
    VirtualScriptAlias "/Volumes/Work/webs/%2"

    <Directory "/Volumes/Work/webs/%2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It causes this error: "client denied by server configuration". When I replace `<Directory "/Volumes/Work/webs/%2">` by `<Directory "/Volumes/Work/webs/myproject">` it works fine...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Directory>` definition does not use the same logic as the directives from `mod_vhost_alias` - to it, the `%2` is just a `%2`, not the second part of the domain the request is for.

Just use `<Directory /Volumes/Work/webs/>` instead, since that applies to all of its subdirectories.